# Trying to uninstall and reinstall python 3 on a mac and messed up files

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew

I tried to link to an old version of python and along the way broke my python3 install. When I started I had python 3.7.7 installed with brew and installed 3.6.8 to revert to. I'm not sure exactly what I did but I broke things and tried to uninstall python3 in order to reinstall. Now, though, when I run `python3 --version` I get `-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3: No such file or directory`. I had deleted the Python.framework file while trying to uninstall after reading a page that said to uninstall I have to delete service files that the app created while using it. Running `which python3` returns nothing, so it seems like I have correctly uninstalled, but if I run brew install python, it will still return the above output if I run `python3 --version`. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Can you run `brew doctor` and `brew config` for me?

Comment: `brew doctor` returned `Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew cleanup`:`. Running `brew cleanup` fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, glad it worked out!